# Automate SVN UP process on multiple application servers

Tags: php, svn

I have multiple PHP application servers having their own svn checkout copy. Now when i need to deploy anything i have to do svn up on all servers one by one.

Is there any way to automate this process and from one command i can push code on all servers. Having code on shared NFS is an option which i do not want to opt.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have post-commit hook on repository, which sends *some signal* to all app-servers when it needed, which they can interpret and process according to your needs (client-side also must be written by you)

Comment: This is essentially how you automate syncing multiple repositories with `svn sync`, you add a post-commit hook to the source that sends the sync commands to the other repos (from memory. It was a long time ago).